# How to replace 'Enter key' search with a search button

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a searchable job listing database on my site, but it doesn't have a search button, it's just responding to the Enter key to trigger the search.

So 'keyword' box and 'location' box are filled in, but instead of pressing a button, you need to press the Enter key.

Is there a way of changing this?

HTML:

```html
<div class="search_jobs">
  <div class="search_keywords">
    <label for="search_keywords">Keywords</label>
    <input type="text" name="search_keywords" id="search_keywords" placeholder="Keywords" value="" />
  </div>
  <div class="search_location">
    <label for="search_location">Location</label>
    <input type="text" name="search_location" id="search_location" placeholder="Location" value="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add an

```html
<input type="submit" value="submit">
```

in the form